# rsync not quitting and running next rsync

Tags: shell-script, shell, rsync

I have a shell script that has 6 rsync commands. What it should do is run the first and then move on to the next. However, what it does right now is do the first once it is finished it'll hang and just say: `receiving incremental file list`

This is what the command looks like:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh user@sever.name.net:/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/* /dir/dir/dir/dir/
```

Why is it that the command just hangs like this instead of going to the next rsync command?

Comment: Why do you have `*` at the end of the source directory? What will that `*` match, files or directories? Are there _thousands_ of things in there that the `*` will match? What happens if you remove the `*`.  Also, drop the `-z` unless you have a _very slow connection_, and `-e ssh` too (it's the default).

Answer (score 0):

Drop the z perhaps its taking to long to compress if there are a lots of files. 
Try rsync with just the options -avn see if there is any difference.
This of course assumes the normal things like being able to scp the files from that location to your current location and permissions etc.

Comment: With just -avh it gives me this error: `Unexpected remote arg: user@server.name.net:/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/*
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1214) [sender=3.0.9]` when I do -avhe I still get receiving incremental file list

Comment: Try this. I use it too keep remote folders backed up and it works flawlessly running on a cronjob. rsync -arWPb username@serveraddress:/path/required/ /destination/required/